# How can I clean flash Moto C Plus (xt1723) rom?

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing

1. Where can I find a legit Moto C Plus xt1723 (EU) rom and how can I make sure it's good?
2. Is there a way to clean flash without removing TWRP?
3. What's the simplest way to do it?
4. How can I then root it?

Comment: There are at least 3 questions here: 1) finding ROM (off-topic) & make sure it's good (opinion-based), 2) clean flash (on-topic), 3) root (on-topic). Please focus on 1 question per post.